# multiple filtering in angular by select,checkbox and show by button

Tags: angularjs, select, button, checkbox, filter

I had some code 
https://jsfiddle.net/Dimetrius/58917Ldt/

And I need help. I need filtering by select and checkbox and then show result by click on button. But all of the list needs to be showed  at start.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/58917Ldt/2/

```
  <div ng-repeat="wine in (main.wines | filter: main.filterByCategory 
 |filter:model.names ) as filteredWines" ng-if="main.tab==true">
{{ wine.name }} <i>({{ wine.category }})</i>
 </div>
```

I have created fiddle but it is not very practical though it meets your requirements.

Comment: Thnks. But It's not exactly what  i need.